# ZF2 set static dbAdapter in config loader

Tags: zend-framework2, database-connection, bootstrapping

I have following setup in my development.global.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
           'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
           'dbAdapter' => function($sm) {

                $config = $sm->get('config');
                $config = $config['db'];
                $dbAdapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config);
                return $dbAdapter;
            },
        ),
     ),
```

An then, I'm loading static adapter in onBootstrap() of one of Module's Model class:

```
 $dbAdapter = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('dbAdapter');
 \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($dbAdapter);
```

Is there any possibility to set that just once in config autoloader ? Currrently, if I do that, I still need to call setStaticLOader somewhere in the Module code.

**UPDATE:** as stated below, that's imposible - at least by standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not avoid calling it explicitly in onBootstrap.

General rule is for global/static state to be avoided. Explicitly inject db adapter in factories for you TDG objects instead.

If you still insist on using it, suggest to use delegator factory to make it a bit more flexible. See [blogpost](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-delegator-factories-explained/) for more info about delegators.

Add this to your module config:

```php
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'globalDbAdapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
    ),
    'delegators' => array(
        // Use alias to make it easier to chose which adapter to set as global
        'globalDbAdapter' => array(
            'YourModule\Factory\GlobalDbAdapterDelegator',
        ),
    ),
)
```

and then delegator factory:

```php
namespace YourModule\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\DelegatorFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature;

class GlobalDbAdapterDelegator implements DelegatorFactoryInterface
{
    public function createDelegatorWithName(
        ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator,
        $name,
        $requestedName,
        $callback
    ) {
        $dbAdapter = $callback();
        GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($dbAdapter);

        return $dbAdapter;
    }
}
```

and finally in onBootstrap method

```
// Force creation of service
$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('globalDbAdapter');
```

Comment: HI, many thanks for your input, but - maybe I'm missing something - finally you need to call service manager in the onBootstrap anyway, no ? :)

Comment: yes. As i said, there is no way around that. Unless you will stop using global db adapter. Which is a strongly recommended approach.

Comment: well, then I'll move back to ZF1 I think. I hoped, that ZF2 will make some things easier, but unfortunately I'm sinking in a lot of manual operations. Many thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: btw, I'm accepting your response, as now it's clear, that I can't simply do that :)